# Target the text before a a class inside a div

Tags: html, css

I have this div

```
<div>
    Questions about these terms
    <ol class="alphabetical">
      <li>
        <div>If you have any questions about these terms or the Platform, you may contact us by email at
          <a href="mailto:support@example.com">support@example.como</a>.</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div>Our VAT number is {vat}.</div>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </div>
```

i have other divs

```
<div>
content here...
</div>
```

within the same document. I want to bold this text in particular

```
**Questions about these terms**
    <ol class="alphabetical">
```

that occurs just before this class `<ol class="alphabetical">`

and this doesnt work

```
.alphabetical::before {
 font-weight:bold !important;
}
```

Is there a way i can target the text in plain css?

Answer (score 3):

Different ways to do this, some methods are

1. Wrap text you want to be bold i html `<b></b>`-tags
2. Wrap text you want to be bold i html `<span></span>`-tags, then style that span with css
3. Set `font-weight` on parent div, then use `font-weigth: initial;` on the `ol`-element selector.

Answer (score 0):

#### You can not access this text with that selector.

Instead, wrap it to another inline element like `span`, `b`, or others, and then get this element with selector:

```css
span.header {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <span class="header">Questions about these terms</span>
    <ol class="alphabetical">
      <li>
        <div>If you have any questions about these terms or the Platform, you may contact us by email at
          <a href="mailto:support@example.com">support@example.como</a>.</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div>Our VAT number is {vat}.</div>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </div>
```

See: How [::before](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) works.

### Update:

If you want to get this text without wrapping it you can use this:

```html
<div class="container">
    Questions about these terms
    <ol class="alphabetical">
      <li>
        <div>If you have any questions about these terms or the Platform, you may contact us by email at
          <a href="mailto:support@example.com">support@example.como</a>.</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div>Our VAT number is {vat}.</div>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </div>
```

```css
/* Selects each <div>, but only if it is the */
/* only <div> element inside its parent */
/* without container class */

div:only-of-type {
  font-weight: bold;
}
div > * {
  font-weight: initial;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the text in a div or p (or both) and give that a class and style it. For example:

```
<div>
    <p class="foo">Questions about these terms </p>
    <ol class="alphabetical">
      <li>
        <div>If you have any questions about these terms or the Platform, you may contact us by email at
          <a href="mailto:support@example.com">support@example.como</a>.</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div>Our VAT number is {vat}.</div>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </div>
```

And the css:

```
.foo {
 font-weight: bold;
}
```